# Alterar código JavaScript para tag vídeo redimensionada

Tags: javascript, html5

[Neste link](http://progdesenv.com.br/tapetv/redimensiona.php) eu tenho uma página de teste onde o vídeo na tela é redimensionado conforme a seleção do select.

Eu preciso que ao carregar a página venha carregada a função da seleção transform do select, mas como eu não preciso do select, só da função do transform, eu tentei modificar e não consegui o resultado que queria.

#### Código

```
var $player = $('#player');
var player = $player.get(0);
var $parent = $player.parent();
var $win = $(window);
var resizeTimeout = null;
var shouldResize = false;
var shouldPosition = false;
var videoRatio = 16 / 9;

player.volume = 0; // mute

var resize = function() {
  if (!shouldResize) { return; }

  var height = $parent.height();
  var width = $parent.width();
  var viewportRatio = width / height;
  var scale = 1;

  if (videoRatio < viewportRatio) {
    // viewport more widescreen than video aspect ratio
    scale = viewportRatio / videoRatio;
  } else if (viewportRatio < videoRatio) {
    // viewport more square than video aspect ratio
    scale = videoRatio / viewportRatio;
  }

  var offset = positionVideo(scale, width, height);
  setVideoTransform(scale, offset);
};

var setVideoTransform = function(scale, offset) {
  offset = $.extend({ x: 0, y: 0 }, offset);
  var transform = 'translate(' + Math.round(offset.x) + 'px,' + Math.round(offset.y) + 'px) scale(' + scale  + ')';
  $player.css({
    '-webkit-transform': transform,
    'transform': transform
  });
};

// accounts for transform origins on scaled video
var positionVideo = function(scale, width, height) {
  if (!shouldPosition) { return false; }

  var x = parseInt($player.data('origin-x'), 10);
  var y = parseInt($player.data('origin-y'), 10);
  setVideoOrigin(x, y);

  var viewportRatio = width / height;
  var scaledHeight = scale * height;
  var scaledWidth = scale * width;
  var percentFromX = (x - 50) / 100;
  var percentFromY = (y - 50) / 100;
  var offset = {};

  if (videoRatio < viewportRatio) {
    offset.x = (scaledWidth - width) * percentFromX;
  } else if (viewportRatio < videoRatio) {
    offset.y = (scaledHeight - height) * percentFromY;
  }

  return offset;
};

var setVideoOrigin = function(x, y) {
  var origin = x + '% ' + y + '%';
  $player.css({
    '-webkit-transform-origin': origin,
    'transform-origin': origin
  });
};

$win.on('resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(resize, 100);
});

$('#select').on('change', function(e) {
  var selected = $(this).children(':selected');
  var value = selected.val();
  player.setAttribute('style', '');
  switch (value) {
    case 'transform':
      shouldResize = true;
      shouldPosition = false;
      resize();
      break;

    case 'transform-origin':
      shouldResize = true;
      shouldPosition = true;
      resize();
      break;

    default:
      shouldResize = false;
      shouldPosition = false;
  }
  player.setAttribute('class', value);
});
```

Comment: Estou vendo sua pergunta um pouco tarde, mas no link passado não há select algum. Você conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque o link apresentado não mostra o problema, nem há explicação de qual o problema com o código publicado.